# chrome extension unload event in background js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have created a chrome extension which is connected to Native messaging application. Native messaging app needs to know if the extension is unchecked or unloaded. Is there any event by which i can catch that the extension is uninstalled or unchecked? So that i can send message to my native messaging app to notify

Comment: Have you tried [window.onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers.onunload)?

Comment: @abraham: No, but i dont think it would work, Let me try and get back to you

Comment: @abraham: Its not working . :(

Comment: The next option is to have your extension send a ping ever X seconds and if they stop the app knows the extension is no longer available.

Comment: @abraham: I found an event "chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener". but it is not working as expected.

Comment: Looks like that only works for [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) which are background pages with `"persistent": false` set in the manifest.json.

Comment: @abraham ; Yes, I m doing persistent : false also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311204/chrome-runtime-onsuspend-addlistener-not-firing

Comment: As far as i know (beware, I know little) the Native Messaging Process is automatically killed by chrome when you "uncheck" the extension. Did I miss something, here?

Answer (score 0):

This can simply be detected if reading from STDIN when listening for messages from the browser in the native messaging host fails (e.g. `fread` returns not the buffer length passed in). Google Chrome disconnects STDIN when it unloads the extension.