# chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener not firing

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am having a chrome extension connected to native messaging application. I need to do some cleanup when the chrome extension suspends. I am trying to use chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener but it is not working. Here is my code : -

Manifest.json

```
"background": {"scripts": ["background.js"], 
               "persistent": false},
```

background.js

```
    function Connect() {
        console.log("Connected");

        ext = chrome.runtime.connectNative('foxtrot');   
        chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener(function () {
            ext.postMessage({ message: "clean and close" });   
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is the port working otherwise?

Comment: @Xan : yes, It is sending other messages.

Comment: Do alerts trigger in the listener?

Comment: @abraham: No, even when i use to set localstorage, it is not working